# React-Native & Android: How to request for Permissions

Tags: android, react-native

I have a React-Native Android module and I need to show a snackbar so that the user accepts permissions.

Not sure why the line that I have commented as "// HERE IS THE PROBLEM:" fails:

(Please see the code below)

```
private void requestLocationPermission() {

    final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 10;
    ViewGroup containerView;

    try {
        containerView = (ViewGroup) getCurrentActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    if (containerView == null) return;

    if (!hasLocationPermissions()) {
        Snackbar.make(containerView,
                R.string.location_services_request,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction(R.string.action_enable, new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // HERE IS THE PROBLEM:
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
            }
        }).show();
    }
}
```

Maybe the "requestPermissions" should not be static but a method of the react-native activity? How would this line be re-written for react-native?

Thanks!